# Headlight one low one high beam

Tags: electrical

passenger always on high beam when drivers side is low. Both go hi when switched but pnly drivers side goes back
On a 2008 jeep liberty sport

Comment: Check the bulb in the passenger side first - it sounds like it has an internal short. After that you should check the wiring.